# Theme Luma issues

Tags: custom, header

For my online store I want use Luma theme and in priciple all good, but I need modify little structure, I need below menu add custom links list (which will be displayed on all pages) - I have .phtm file with my hardcode structure, I want to place it here: https://prnt.sc/1106w4z and above footer I need add my location stores - also hardcode in .phtml and need to place here: https://prnt.sc/1106wgr.

After reading on the forum, I saw that you can use the default.xml for this, but how should this file look correctly where can I connect my .phtml files to display in under the header and footer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done from layout. I would suggest to create a child theme based on "Luma Theme" for this. Learn how to create child theme here:

1. https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-child-theme-in-magento-2/
2. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html

After that:

Create a file `app/design/frontend/your_theme/theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your.unique.name" template="Magento_Theme::html/my-template.phtml" before="top.container" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```